# ¿Se puede hacer un inner join con una tabla local y una API?

Tags: laravel

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
public function index()
{
    $data = file_get_contents("MIAPI");
    $users = json_decode($data, true);
    $users = collect($users);

    $webusers = User::all();

    return view('users.index', compact('users', 'webusers'));
}
```

Requiero hacer un match entre un campo de `$users` y otro `$webusers` para verificar cuales usuarios de la API tienen cuenta en la Web, si no se puede no se me ocurre de cual otra manera podría solventarlo.

Comment: Falta información en tu pregunta. ¿Eres también el programador de la API? ¿Están las BD en servidores distintos y corren en el mismo SGBD? De ser así, ¿tienes permiso para poder conectar ambas bases de datos?  ¿Cuál es el SGBD en que están las BD?

Comment: Hola, no soy el programador de la API, Sí las base de datos están en servidores distintos, ólvidé decir que era una API externa (de un tercero), son distintos SGBD, el proyecto lo estoy desarrollando en PHP (MySql) y la API fue hecha en .NET, creo que la base de datos está en SQLServer... Tengo permiso de lectura de la API

Comment: Pues deberás ensamblar todo en tu código, una vez hayas recibido la respuesta de la API, comparar esos datos con los que tienes en tu base de datos.

Comment: Pienso que debo usar dos modelos, uno lo tengo, el de la base de datos local `User`, pero como hago que agregar la `API` al `JOIN` si no tiene un Modelo, si se puede no sé como hacerlo.

Comment: La API es una fuente de datos, como la base de datos, un archivo u otro. El modelo lo creas tú y puedes mapear la respuesta de la API a ese modelo, del mismo modo que mapeas el resultado de la consulta SQL que haces a la BD. El problema es que estás fijado en hacer un JOIN (SQL) pero el entorno no te permite eso, tienes que hacerlo de otro modo, por ejemplo comparando la respuesta de la API con lo que obtienes de la BD.

Comment: Sí, se me ocurre hacer un foreach con los datos de la API y dentro un for para recorrer cada registro de la base de datos local para comparar, ¿esa sería una manera correcta de hacerlo? ¿si es eficiente?

Comment: Lo que dices es quizá lo más factible, puedes ir comparando e incluso quizá ir construyendo un objeto con el resultado final que podrías mapear a tu modelo de datos. Sería lo mismo que si hicieras un JOIN, pero uniendo los datos de otro modo, porque el contexto actual no te permite hacer JOIN.